# Create pgAdmin database on local machine

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to create databases on my local machine using pgAdmin. When I try to connect to a new server using the "New server registration" entry below it gives me the "Server doesn't listen" error (picture below). 
[image: log_in_attempt]
[image: error_message]
I had tried the same procedure on my previous machine and it worked without any trouble. Any thoughts would be very helpful. I've tried some different combinations and nothing has worked yet. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you installed the PostgreSQL server?

Comment: Do you have anything to say to the things asked in the error message?

Comment: Erwin, I have checked the firewall settings and other error messages, and I didn't see anything there that corresponded to the error. Fabrizio, because I don't have administrator privileges on my computer my IT department had to download the package. I had asked them to download the entire package including PostrgeSQL server and pgAdmin, but I will need to check with them. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 9):

PgAdmin is just a tool to work on existing database. @FabrizioMazzoni is right - you have to install PostgreSQL server first, and the you can use PgAdmin to work on it. New Server Registration is a form to connect to an existing database server, not to create one.

Comment: Thanks Adam, as I noted in my comment above I'll need to check with my IT department to see if they downloaded the entire package or not.